# should mail.jar and activation.jar go into CATALINA/lib?

Tags: tomcat, log4j, jakarta-mail

I have several apps which require email (smtp) but also want Tomcat's own ERROR messages to be emailed.  I've found this works only if I put mail.jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib and remove it from all the webapps (~/WEB-INF/lib)

First question: should activation.jar also go into Tomcat's lib folder?

Second question is: What happens if an unmonitored app includes these jars in its own lib? (it seems this breaks the log4j emails for Tomcat.  I'm confused why Tomcat doesn't find and use the classses in its own lib rather than throwing a smtp mail provider exception (presumably due to the multiple occurances of the same mail.jar in the classpath).

Answer (score 0):

Those jars **have** to be on Tomcat's classpath if Tomcat uses them. Even if some webapp includes them too, every webapp has its own class loader and these jars are not visible to the lower level tomcat. The WebbappClassLoader implements the child-first delegation model in contrast to the Java default parent-first model.

Comment: thanks.  what isn't clear though is why the Email Appender for Tomcat messages failed when the mail.jar was included not just in the $catalina_home/lib folder but also in one of the webapp lib folders.  as soon as I removed the mail.jar from the webapp things worked.  makes me nervous that someone inadvertently putting mail.jar into a webapp breaks the log4j email appender for Tomcat-leel log messages.  The error is 'no provider' found, which seems to indicate a classpath issue (not finding the properties file in mail.jar).